# TriangleTube Smart 30 digital thermostat

Tags: plumbing, thermostat, water-heater

I have a TriangleTube Smart 30 indirect water heater which unfortunately only comes with an analog (red top blue dial) thermostat. I would really love to find a way to get a digital thermostat on it so I can set it to a certain temperature instead of "partially red". Anyone have the same experience or any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your boiler, you can at least see the DHW called temperature on your boiler display. I have the Smart 30 water heater coupled with a Triangle Tube Prestige Solo boiler, and on its display, under the various info items, I can see the DHW temperature. I'm guessing that will be the closest you can get with this specific setup.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately my 14 year old Burnham boiler doesn't have that kind of feature either.